# is shebang considered to be a special case of comment?

Tags: bash, shell, shebang

If we are specifying syntactically parts of the shell script, where should shebang go, is it a special case of comment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shebang is not handled specially by shell syntax (either for the baseline POSIX sh standard, or in bash specifically) at all. That is: It's not a special case of comment to the shell; rather, *to the shell*, it's a completely normal, bog-standard comment with no special handling whatsoever.

See the formal syntax at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02; there's nothing specific to the shebang at all.

The only special handling is done *before the shell is even started*, when the operating system -- when directed to start a new program via the `execve()` syscall -- is trying to find an interpreter (be it a shell or something else) with which to invoke an executable to replace the process image formerly associated with the active PID.

Comment: The first two characters #! represent the [magic byte string being 0x23 0x21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Magic_number) used (as mentioned) by exec functions to determine if it's a script or a binary executable.

Used also by `file` Linux utility to determine the file type based on those magic bytes rather than on the file extension.

On Linux:  

`$ echo "#!/my_interpreter" > script`  
`$ file script`  
`script: a /my_interpreter  script, ASCII text executable`

Comment: Those magic bytes are also used by [Apache mod_mime_magic module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime_magic.html).